# Порядковый номер 279 не найден в библиотеке DLL VISA32.dll?

Tags: c++, dll

Суть проблемы:

1. У меня есть собранная программа, которая написана на С++. Программа работает с оборудованием. (Оборудование у меня тоже есть).
2. Программа прекрасно работает на Win32 (Windows **7**). Когда я её запустил на компьютере с Win32 (Windows **XP**), вывелось:

***"Порядковый номер 279 не найден в библиотеке DLL VISA32.dll"***

Уважаемые коллеги, может у вас есть идеи, как это пофиксить?
Обращаю внимание, что библиотека VISA32.dll на двух компьютерах одна и та же: я скопировал эту библиотеку с Windows **7** в Windows **XP**.

Comment: вполне возможно, что библиотека visa32.dll была скомпилирована без поддержки хп. В этом случае вполне возможно, что заставить ее работать будет невозможно (без перекомпиляции).

Comment: @KoVadim а не могли бы вы подсказать, где можно дёрнуть эту библиотеку под XP? Я полинтернета облазил - всё бестолку.

Comment: Видимо нужно обращаться к производителю оборудования.

Comment: visa32.dll стоит по умолчанию. В папке C:\Windows\System32

Comment: проверил на нескольких своих системах - нет такого файла.

Comment: Проверьте чем-то все библиотеки/функции которые подключает ваш модуль, например exescope. Там же можно версию os проверить.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin visa32.dll не поставляется в составе Windows, она ставится при установке специального ПО или драйверов к вашему оборудованию.

Comment: @Cerbo да спасибо. Вы правы.